# toad custom filter query fail

Tags: toad, quest

Im using this tool name as TOAD http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/  for mysql analysis, At the data compare wizard , when I type in a sql query it tells me that the query is fine, I  tested the query in phpMyAdmin it worked well.

http://toadformysql.com/thread.jspa?threadID=37479

The query :

```
  SELECT firstName from user where id=1 LIMIT 1
```

Table Name is : user
id firstName lastName
1 Bill Smith
2 John Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By filter , it means the WHERE part of sql query